# Find $x$ so that $h(x)=\text{max}(f(x),g(x))$ assumes its min value

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, graphing-functions, maxima-minima

**Problem:**

> Given: $f(x) = x^2 + 12x – 6, \qquad g(x) = 3x – 6 – x^2$
> If $h(x)=\text{max}(f(x),g(x))$, find $x$ so that $h(x)$ assumes it's min value.

**My Approach:**

> I was told that, **in all such questions**, simply do $f(x)=g(x)$ to find $x$.
> So, that I did, to get $x=0,-4.5$.
> Thus, I answered that at $x=-4.5$ we'll get the min value of $h(x)$.

**Surprise:**

> Here's how the graph looks(!):
> [image]
> As we can notice that the actual minima of $h(x)$ occurs at $x=-6$ which is same as the minima of $f(x)$.

**Question:**

> What is the correct approach to tackle such problem(s) or rather to check that such a thing is happening (as it feels rare phenomenon to me)?
> Also, could there be some other variant(s) too where simple $f(x)=g(x)$ fails?

Comment: A way would be to find the extrema for $f$ and $g$, calculate both functions at them, use that knowledge to determine $h$ at those points, and then use a continuity argument to say that $h$ cannot assume it's minimum anywhere else.

Comment: To the other part of the question: It's exceedingly rare that the solution to $f(x)=g(x)$ will have any connection to the minima of any compound function. Where were you told that lie?

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity it's not true, for example take $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = 1 - x^2$ - the minima of $h$ is not extreme for any of $f$ or $g$.

Comment: @mihaild: You're right, you also need to examine the points where $f(x)=g(x)$.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity I've tried at least 20 similar problems, and there it was working what I was told. But in the above case, it apparently failed. Perhaps questions were deliberately made that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there is no reason that $f(x) = g(x)$ should give you min value for $h(x)$. When you draw graphs for $f$ and $g$, $f(x) = g(x)$ gives you points where the graphs intersect - such points separate segments where $f(x) < g(x)$ from segments where $f(x) > g(x)$, but both function can still be arbitrary big or small in any of this segments.

The correct approach (for continuous $f$ and $g$, pretty much any you will encounter most of the time) is to solve $f(x) = g(x)$, get solutions $x_0, x_1, \ldots, x_n$, then on every segment, as well as on $(-\infty, x_0)$ and $(x_n, \infty)$ you have either $f \geq g$ or $f \leq g$ - so you find minimum of corresponding function on this segment, and then aggregate them between segments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. +1.

Comment: So, "and then on every segment..." - You mean that I also need to check min of both the functions outside of domain $[x_0,x_n]$ assuming those values of $x$ as smallest and largest respectively?

Comment: @InanimateBeing yes, added. The main idea is that points $x_i$ split the domain in parts, and on each part you have to solve the problem separately.

Comment: Alright, thank you for clarifying.